# Сканер отпечатков пальцев/сетчатки глаза/лица с API?

Tags: проект

Требуется сканер отпечатков пальцев,сетчатки глаза или лица с подключением к компьютеру (ОС Windows XP, 7,8,10) к возможностью написания программ

Comment: Посмотрите на [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) (Open Source Computer Vision). А вообще, переформулируйте вопрос, пожалуйста, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ. Опишите вашу задачу, уровень специалистов, что уже смотрели и чем не подошло и т.п.

Comment: На работе постоянно приходят новые сотрудники +4-5 человек в месяц и нужно чтобы сканер мог заносить данные в БД и сравнивая данные отправлять данные обратно в БД или на свою написанную программу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой задачи есть [универсальный API Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd560897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Данное решение лучше в том плане, что вы не привязываетесь к конкретному железу.